# How can I change the height of a button with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, height

Depending on the height of the screen, I would like to adjust the height of a button in a view. What is the easiest way to do this in Swift?

I tried it in this way and also with `CGRectMake()` but nothing changed:

```
self.myButton.frame.size.height = self.myButton.frame.size.height*scrOpt
```

How can I "update" the frame?

Comment: `self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.myButton.frame.origin.x, self.myButton.frame.origin.y, self.myButton.frame..size.width, self.myButton.frame.size.height*scrOpt)`

Comment: If you are using auto layout, you need to update its height constraint, else update its frame.

Comment: See explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16406097/790842. As @YogeshSuthar said, you must be using AutoLayout, and in AutoLayout changing frames doesn't work, you need to work on constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you see no changes may be because you're using AutoLayout, and the button has some constraints applied to it, and you need to change the height constraint to accomplish what you want.

**Edited**: Changing frame properties directly seems to be possible in Swift but was not possible in Objective C.

Comment: `frame` is not a read-only property, and you *can* assign to `self.myButton.frame.size.height` in Swift ...

Comment: Yep, that seems the problem - I have AutoLayout on (what seems to work well in general) and try to change this stupid button now in the code... Hmmm... :-/ Thx!

Comment: You're right Martin. I got used to that from Objective C. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto layout, you need to update its height constraint, else update its frame

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.myButton.frame));

    NSLog(@"%f",scrOpt);

    self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.myButton.frame.origin.x, self.myButton.frame.origin.y, self.myButton.frame.size.width, self.myButton.frame.size.height*scrOpt)

    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.myButton.frame));
```

Edited check this and see what is Print `NSLog`